# Web Link format. With or without .html suffix

Tags: links

On our company website most links are in the form:

```
http://www.example.com/contact.html
```

Is it a better idea to have

```
http://www.example.com/contact
```

Or does it not matter. I got thinking because when I was submitting a form at google Adsense it refused to let me have a "." in the sub-page link modifier (see below "Path" box).

Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: What type of adsense form you're talking about? Any reference link/source about that form?

Comment: @Goyllo Thanks. I added the relevant box above. In the Path field it does not seem to let me enter a page.html.

Comment: As Goyllo asked, "Any reference link/source about that form?" - If the form is not letting you enter a "dot" in the value, then it would seem you are entering the wrong value? Including a `.html` suffix on the URL is perfectly "normal".

Comment: @w3dk Yes, maybe I am doing it wrong. I'm using it for the first time. Maybe some other adsense user can throw light on this?

Answer (score 3):

> Or does it not matter.

It most probably does not matter. There is no direct SEO benefit to dropping the `.html` suffix on the URL. In fact, changing the URL in any way might even see a marginal/temporary drop in rankings (maybe).

The only reason to remove the "extension" on URLs is to *possibly* make it more "user friendly" and a little bit shorter. Easier for users to remember and type. Looks a little neater when links are published. Possibly improve click-through rates in the SERPs (although that's debatable for such a minor change).

If you had a technology specific extension like `.php` or `.asp` then it can be beneficial to remove this technology "flag", but `.html` is already generic and not technology specific. In fact, there has been a bit of a trend in recent years to move back to a `.html` extension.

> when I was submitting a form at google Adsense it refused to let me have a "." in the sub-page link modifier

This is probably because you are entering the wrong type of information in this form field. Having dots in URLs, particularly the `.html` extension is perfectly "normal".

Comment: I think this question is about adwords campaign, not about SEO or AdSense.

Comment: @Goyllo Hhmmm yes, that is possibly the intended question (+1). Although they have still asked the other question about possible benefits of removing the `.html` extension (maybe because of the initial confusion).

Comment: Yeah, that's right :)

Answer (score 3):

The path URL is not real URL address, it's dummy URL address, which made for marketing purpose, so user can understand your ads in better way and you get more clicks.

For example this URL is very buggy for ads `www.example.poduct/id/2521.aspx`

What if you can display below URL in your ad campaign, behind your actual URL.

```
www.example.com/Mens_Shoes/Outdoor
```

It's look great then above URL. And you will get more clicks.

So the path is not real and that's why they might not allowed to use dot .(Sorry I have never tried like that) . The actual path or your landing page URL (ln this example www.example.com/contact/) should be given in **final URL textbox**, so whenever anybody click on your ads then that final URL will be open on their browser.

Here is more details about [paths in adwords ads.](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/7046795?hl=en)

Comment: Ohhhh! Now I get it. Thanks for explaining this! Makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .htaccess file in the main directory.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

After this time you can access your html files with only names. You don't need to add ".html" extension. There is an important thing. If you enter filename.html via browser then you get 404 error. Becouse server trying to find filename.html.html file. Don't forget this.